# Exporting SQL Server 2005 database to CSV - Columns contain only question marks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to export a SQL Server 2005 database using ESF Database Migration Toolkit to `.CSV`, which I can then - hopefully - manipulate enough to create an Import file for importing into WordPress.

However, the current site is in Korean language and shall remain in Korean on the new server running MySQL.

After exporting all of the tables, I am finding columns where I would expect to find "some korean string" to contain "T???? ?????? ?????" - no Korean words in sight! I have tried exporting using ANSI, OEM and UNICODE options in ESF, each provides the same result.

Anyone?

Comment: Does the ESF Database Migration Toolkit Support Korean? YOu may also run into a problem if the columns aren't in NCHAR or NVARCHAR datatype. I am not at all familiar ESF Database Migration Toolkit that is just what i know from the SQL Server side of things.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Yes, ESF does support Korean. Strangely, my first attempt a couple of months ago exported just fine but since then a lot of new content has been added - hence the need to get the latest database. I have tried using MySQL Workbench to at least convert across to a MySQL database which I find much easier to understand and work with, but cannot even get that to work - with an unrelated 'Authentication plugin mysql_old_password cannot be loaded' error. Arghhh!!